# App.Config Projeto em Camadas

Tags: c#, web-service

Senhores, tenho uma aplicação em camadas, a camada de negócios contém uma referência ao WebServiceCorreios. No App.config da camada de de negócios tive que adicionar o seguinte código:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="AtendeClienteServiceSoapBinding">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
            <binding name="AtendeClienteServiceSoapBinding1" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://apps.correios.com.br/SigepMasterJPA/AtendeClienteService/AtendeCliente"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="AtendeClienteServiceSoapBinding"
            contract="WebServiceCorreios.AtendeCliente" name="AtendeClientePort" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Acontece que quando compilo a aplicação o arquivo App.Config da camada GUI está sendo usado.

Gostaria de usar a classe que criei para o WebServiceCorreios em vários outros projetos sem ter que alterar o App.Config toda vez que for reutilizar esta classe.

Existe alguma forma de a aplicação não usar o App.Config do projeto setado como "StartUp Project" e sim do projeto que contem a classe do Webservice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você mesmo disse, o arquivo **App.config** utilizando é o do **Startup Project**. Geralmente alterar esse comprotamento não é uma boa ideia, pois pode gerar problemas futuros, ainda mais se estiver trabalhando em equipe.
Digo isso porque você está querendo alterar uma funcionalidade padrão, ou seja, outras pessoas podem não saber disso, ou você mesmo pode acabar esquecendo disso no futuro.

Mas, se realmente quer fazer isso, existe algumas formas, que irei listar abaixo:

### 1. Definir o [ConfigurationFileMap.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.configuration.configurationfilemap(v=vs.110).aspx)

Dessa forma você pode alterar o arquivo padrão de onde estará obtendo as configurações para o **App.config**.

```
ConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ConfigurationFileMap(file); //Path to your config file
Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(fileMap);
string value = configuration.AppSettings.Settings["key1"].Value;
```

### 2. Adicionar o arquivo como um link.

Dessa forma você irá adicionar o **App.config** como se fosse um arquivo externo. Para fazer isso, basta seguir os passos abaixo:

1. Botão direito do mouse seu projeto no **Solution Explorer**
2. Selecione  **"Add" -> "Existing Item..."**
3. Navegue até o arquivo que você deseja adicionar à solução
4. **Em vez de pressionar Enter ou clicar no botão Add**, você quer clique no ícone de seta para baixo na extremidade direita do botão Adicionar e selecione **"Add As Link".**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### 3.Adicionar o valor em classe ao invés do **App.config**.

Essa forma é simples, basta adicionar o valor fixo na classe.

#### 4. Utilizar o [SlowCheetah XML Transformation](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5)

Com essa forma você irá utilizar o **XML Transformation** para isso.

Existe [essa extensão para o Visual Studio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) que possa lhe auxiliar.
[Neste link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8125657/4843158) você encontra uma excelente explicação do que é e como usar.
Referências:

- [Using app.config when referencing different projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15550663/4843158)
- [single app.config multi-project c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1361913/4843158)

> Existem outras formas de fazer isso, mas as mais simples que eu conheço são essas.

Comment: Obrigado Randrade, também concordo sobre a geração de problemas futuros. Vou pensar mais a respeito e posto uma edição sobre como vou resolver. Mais uma vez muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Não seria melhor você usar a https://github.com/hamboldt/Correios.Net que já contém as chamadas para o webservice prontas ?

Comment: duardbr, eu até podeira usar, porem como sou iniciante gostaria de desenvolver minha própria classe para fins didáticos, e futuramente se ela se apresentar realmente útil, disponibiliza-lá para a comunidade.